# How to redirect to an HTML classic asp page from Lotus notes form

Tags: html, redirect, asp-classic, lotusscript

There is a requirement in our application to add a Button in our lotus notes Form. 
And on click of this button, the user will be redirected to a HTML or Classic ASP page.
We also want to pass the value of a textbox present in the same form, to the HTML /asp page.

I am new to Lotus notes scripting. Though with the help of internet, I am able to create a button in the form. But I dont find any solution to redirect the user to the required HTML /asp page.

Your help will be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there's a text field with name `myfield` in your form.

In your form add a button, then set @-formula for this button:

```
@URLOpen("http://www.yourserver.com/yourpage.asp?" + @URLEncode("UTF-8"; myfield));
```

when you click this button it will open asp page and will pass contents of `myfield` in urlencoded form (using UTF-8 encoding) to this page.